# How to append dictionary in array as index in swift 3.0

Tags: swift3

How to add dictionary's key, value in array as array index form, like this

```
[
    {
      "summary": "fdsfvsd"
    },
    {
      "content_date": "1510158480"
    },
    {
      "content_check": "yes"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you expand this question - it's not clear what you want exactly.

Comment: I want append a dictionary in array which have key value on particular index

Comment: Don't post code in comments - edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you want to work with array of dictionaries in Swift, 
here is the simple way to achieve the same :

```
  var arrayOfDict = [[String: String]]()

//creating dictionaries      
         let dict1 = ["name" : "abc" , "city" : "abc1"]
         let dict2 = ["name" : "def" , "city" : "def1"]
         let dict3 = ["name" : "ghi" , "city" : "ghi1"]
         let dict4 = ["name" : "jkl" , "city" : "jkl1"]

//Appending dictionaries to array

         arrayOfDict.append(dict1)
         arrayOfDict.append(dict2)
         arrayOfDict.append(dict3)
         arrayOfDict.append(dict4)


//accessing each and every element of the arrayOfDictionary

         for dict in arrayOfDict{
              for (key, value) in dict {
                   print("the value for \(key) is = \(value)")
              }
         }
```

Hope it helps you!